# Copy Row from one Sheet to another sheet which is linked in the row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have previously been able to copy rows from one Spreadsheet to another, however what I am trying to do now is copy a row to a specific spreadsheet that is linked on the same row and I can't seem to work it out.

I have around 500 rows of names with data (I cannot share a sheet as my firms Google does not allow for sharing externally but I have a screenshot of dummy data below).  I used a formula to find the Unique names and then created a Google Sheet for each person and linked the Sheet back to the master data.

[Master Data Sheet (tab is called Sheet1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgehW.png)

I am looking for a script that will work through the sheet, copying the rows to the link that is on the same row but I just can't figure it out - the following script does not work but I am at a loss so any help would be appreciated.
Apologies if I haven't explained myself very well!!

```
function copyTo(){

var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var data = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = data[i];
  var link = row[3];
  var id = row[4];
  var complete = row[5];

  var COMPLETE = "Complete"

  if(link !== "" && complete !== "Complete"){

    var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("A" + i + ":C" + i);

  var linkID = id.toString()

  var tarSS = DriveApp.getFileById(linkID);
  var tarSheet = tarSS.getSheetbyName("Sheet1");

   var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
  //tarSheet.insertRowAfter(tarRow);
  var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow+1) + ":C" + (tarRow+1));
  
  srcRange.copyTo(tarRange);
  srcSheet.getRange(i+1,6).setValue(COMPLETE)

 }
 }};
```

Comment: what you exactly want as I can understand form your question is that you want to copy data into new sheet using apps script ? where sheet will be created first and then data go into that sheet right ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :).  The Sheets have already been created and are linked in column D, I just need to find a way to copy the row to the sheet linked in the column

Comment: In these two `var tarSS = DriveApp.getFileById(linkID);
  var tarSheet = tarSS.getSheetbyName("Sheet1");` tarSS is a file but it is not an open spreadsheet for that you need to SpreadsheetApp.openByID() or openByUrl()(

Comment: i have posted a solution you can check let me know how this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copyTo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var row = vs[i];
    var link = row[3];
    var id = row[4];
    var complete = row[5];
    var COMPLETE = "Complete"
    if (link !== "" && complete !== "Complete") {
      var rg = sh.getRange("A" + i + ":C" + i);
      var linkID = id.toString()
      var tarSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(linkID);
      var tarSheet = tarSS.getSheetbyName("Sheet1");
      var tarRow = tarSheet.getLastRow();
      var tarRange = tarSheet.getRange("A" + (tarRow + 1) + ":C" + (tarRow + 1));
      rg.copyTo(tarRange);
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 6).setValue(COMPLETE)
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand you question here is the script which will work for you exactly you want .
This will copy data from sheet you want and then create a new spreadsheet and paste into that sheet then link will show of this in same sheet from data copied

Let me know how this worked .

**Code.gs**

```
const sendDataToSheet = () => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName(''paste here your sheet name'') 
  const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("give new sheet name here")   
  ws.copyTo(newSheet).setName("Copied Data")   
  const sheetURL = newSheet.getUrl()
  ws.insertRowBefore(1) 
  ws.getRange(1,1).setValue(sheetURL)

}
```